# How to get Title/text from Microsoft Dynamics 2011 subject

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I want to check the name of a global subject. It tried it with `getText()`, `getName()` and other methods from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx).

Isn't it an attribute?

```
function CheckSubject()
{
  var texter = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subjectid").getValue();

  alert(texter);  // output: [object Object]
  alert(texter.getText());  // output:  Fehler im benutzerdefinierten Ereignis dieses Felds. Feld:subjectid Ereignis:onchange Fehler:undefined

  if(texter=="Incident")
  {
    // DO something
  }
}
```

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subjectid return a lookup object. You this options in a lookup object:

```
var name = texter[0].name;
var guid = texter[0].id;
var entType = texter[0].entityType;
```